# Can an Anonymous User Access the Blockchain?

Tags: corda

Do you have to be a known party on the network to make a transaction?

Can an anonymous user off the network interact with the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

When joining the network, a node needs to obtain a network certificate provided by the network's doorman. This certificate ties the node to a specific real-world identity. When messaging other nodes, a node must use this certificate to allow the receiving nodes to verify who they are transacting with.

However, suppose a node is working with other nodes to build a transaction. Although the node must reveal its identity to the other nodes they are building the transaction with, it can choose to identify itself in the transaction being built using an anonymous one-time public key, rather than a real-world identity.

This means that the node's identity is not stored on the ledger for all to see, and is only known to the nodes with whom the transaction was originally built.

You can also imagine scenarios where even though the node's identity is well-known, the identity of the actual user is not. For example, a node representing an auction house may place a bid on the behalf of an anonymous user.